# How to implement listview & nested layouts in tabbed layout on Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-tabs

I’m new to Android and am working on my 1st app, which is still pretty much a ‘Hello World’ effort at this point.  In my main activity I’d like to have a set of two tabs.  The first tab is a layout that consists of a couple of sub-linear layouts that is basically row of buttons/text on the top and a listview below (edited for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.86"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

The 2nd tab will be a listview filling the whole tab.  I have the above layout working as a my main activity and am trying to evolve to putting it into a tab view and creating the listview in tab 2. Each button and list item click would launch its own respective activity.

I’ve found numerous examples/tutorials of tab implementations using the TabActivity class which appears to be deprecated now.  From what I gather, FragmentActivity seems to be the replacement.

I’ve gotten [this](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/) sample working, but have yet to successfully put a listview into a tab much less my nested layout.  I'll keep trying!

Is the Fragment approach to tabs the currently accepted best practice?  From what I've seen I'm still leaning towards that as a UI solution vs an Action Bar.  I may change my mind after seeing how complex some of these tabbed fragment implementations are.  :-)

Any pointers to good examples which might implement either listviews and/or nested layouts in tabs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I'm new to the Android so I'm not sure that this is the right solution for you but the following exemple use a ListFragment to implement two lists inside tabs with Fragments:

http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

As to the Fragment approach, myself I found it very complicated in comparaison to the old style of using TabActivity.  It looks like that the Android's development team has developed the Fragments for ICS in a hurry (to cover the tablets?) and has choosen to deprecate the TabActivity in order to push everyone toward the use of Fragments but without first taking the time of fully testing them for their usefulness and correctness.

When you replace something simple with something much more complicated and deprecate the older thing without any real obvious advantage of doing so leave the bad impression of a hasty decision and I won't be surprised to see this one reversed in the future (unless we see the ICS kicked out of the tablets' market instead).

Ultimely, the market will decide but from past experience, it doesn't often choose the more complicated way of doing something as the winner; especially when the big advantages don't seem to be there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and thoughts on this. I'd had also seen that sample and will play with it as well. It does seem like there are a lot of quite varied and relatively complicated implementations for this sort of functionality. I was hoping I was missing something easier! :-)